# What is the equivalent of this code in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

What is the equivalent of this code in PowerShell?

```
@echo off

SET PATH=%PATH%;D:\oracle\FRHome_1\dcm\bin\;D:\oracle\FRHome_1\opmn\BIN\;D:\oracle\FRHome_1

\opmn\BIN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $env:PATH=$env:PATH+";D:\oracle\FRHome_1\dcm\bin\;D:\oracle\FRHome_1\opmn\BIN\;D:\oracle\FRHome_1"
```

PS: You should try to learn some Powershell, rather than just asking for equivalent lines of code.

Comment: @MahmoudAL-saadi - Do you know what `@echo off does? If not, I recommend you to learn about it, and see if what it solves is needed in Powershell or not.

Comment: @manojlds - I would argue that asking for equivalents is learning. Albeit an inefficient way.

Comment: @PreetSangha - If you keep converting lines ( this based on his another question just few minutes back ), you only do the same thing you did in bat in powershell, with just the syntax changed. The whole script might be written differently in Powershll.

Comment: am learning .. i finished my code .. just the things I did't find the answer for it its written here

Comment: Thank you all .. promise to learn powershell .. i spent tow days learning it

Comment: @manojlds - I would argue that delivery is sometimes more important than efficiency,